# How does one get table name in SoQL?

Tags: soql

Newbie question.

How does one get the table name for your object? Or is there a way to get the list of all the available table names with soql?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to: Setup.

On the left, you will have the navigation pane.  Go to: Create -> Objects.

Select your object and the object name should show up.
[image]

Comment: Great. So for that example let's say there's a field "Name". To query that i would do something like: 

`Select name from MyCustomObj__c`

correct?

Comment: @chrisjlee Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The table name is really the object API name. So for any custom object you have to define that on creation. You can see the API name of any custom object by going to Setup > Create > Object > Pick the object you want > Look at the "API Name" field.

For the SF delivered objects (I.E Account, Lead, Contact), the table name is just the object name.

Good luck!

Luis Luciani

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a direct query to retrieve all of the available table names in your Salesforce instance. If you use a third party query tool though, you will be able to see all of the objects. I use [SoqlXplorer](http://www.pocketsoap.com/osx/soqlx/), but Workbench or another query tool should work as well.